# How to let an object replace another object?

Tags: swift, object, position

```
@IBAction func red(sender: UIButton) {




    green1.hidden = true
    red1.hidden = false

    blue1.hidden = true



}

@IBAction func blue(sender: UIButton) {

    green1.hidden = true
    red1.hidden = true

    blue1.hidden = false
}

@IBAction func green(sender: UIButton) {
    green1.hidden = false
    red1.hidden = true

    blue1.hidden = true

}
```

how can let the ball appear in the position where the previous ball was appearing when the button is touched?

i want to touch the button of the specific color and then the other ball disappears and the new ball appears in the same position.

Comment: Can you provide more code with position??

Comment: there is no code to do with position as i just set it to the middle in the story board

Answer (score 0):

Set the constraints for balls.

Look here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraints/WorkingwithConstraints.html

Comment: how to do i do that . idid it for the balls in the frame but how does that help?

Comment: yeah i did that but how does this answer my question on how to make the ball appear at the same place?

Comment: Yeah because when u set the constraints it will stay at the position you created by constraints.  Look any videotutorial on youtube how to set constraints.

Comment: yeah but i cancel the constraint in won't fit to every screen